# How to select current day when user was in other months in Datepicker calender by using a clickable button.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have an event calender in my magento website.
I need to redirect users to current date while they are in other months.
I have a button called **TODAY** to write the click event.

**EX : now I am in month of march, I want to go to February by clicking the button TODAY.**
Please see the image I will post here.

I am unable to publish an image, if any one nee an image for this I can send it to you.
Great pleasure if any one can help me on this. Thank you.
**EDIT**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 jQuery(function() {

var jqdpopup = jQuery('#event_popup').dialog({autoOpen: false});
var myDate = new Date();
var prettyDate =(myDate.getMonth()+1) + '/' + myDate.getDate() + '/' +
myDate.getFullYear();


jQuery("#date_input").val(prettyDate);
jQuery('.eventslisting_title span').html(prettyDate);
getevents(prettyDate);
var datesArray=["11/02/2014","11/03/2014"];

jQuery(function(){

    jQuery('#event_calender').datepicker({
         inline: true,
         beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var theday = (date.getMonth()+1) +'/'+ 
                        date.getDate()+ '/' + 
                        date.getFullYear();
                return [true,jQuery.inArray(theday, datesArray) >=0?"eventDate":''];
            },
        onSelect: function(date, obj){
            jQuery('#date_input').val(date);  //Updates value of of your input 
            jQuery('.eventslisting_title span').html(date);
            getevents(date);
            jqdpopup.dialog( "open" );


        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you post some code? Does the calendar export an api?

Comment: Please see the edit part @winhowess.

Comment: someone mark as -1,i am unable to describe my requirement without posting an image.

Comment: Do any of the answers solve your problem? If so, please mark it as correct

Comment: i dont know why people down vote the question.to get a solution only we ask question.can you please tell me the person who down vote the question now why you down vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the `setDate` method in the datepicker api: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate

To set the date by clicking a button do this:

```
jQuery("#buttonID").click(function(){
    jQuery('#event_calender').datepicker( "setDate",  "today");
});
```

Comment: is this question is not a valid question to ask in forum?i dnt know why people are down voting.i got your solution as help full and accepted as answer

Answer (score 1):

On today button click event, write this code

```
 $('#event_calender').datepicker('setDate', 'today');
```